# Генерация случайной строки JS

Tags: javascript, php

Помогите переписать функцию с php на js/jquery

```
function pass_gen($len=8) {//Генерация пароля

    $chrs="abdehkmnpswxzABDEFGHKMNPQRSTWXZ123456789";
    $size=strLen($chrs)-1;
    $pwd=null;

    while($len--)$pwd.=$chrs[rand(0,$size)];

    return $pwd;
}
```

Comment: Познания в js поверхностные. Мне нужно привести аналоги этих функций на js, а дальше я сам. (ваш сарказм не оценил)

Comment: На это можно ответить только советом изучать js для улучшения познаний

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я пользуюсь вот такой реализацией:

```js
console.log(randomString(6))
console.log(randomString(12))
console.log(randomString(44))

function randomString(i) {
    var rnd = '';
    while (rnd.length < i) 
        rnd += Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    return rnd.substring(0, i);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо всем за ценные советы. SO как всегда выручает. Нашел решение

```js
    console.log(pass_gen(6))
    console.log(pass_gen(12))
    console.log(pass_gen(32))
    function pass_gen(len) {
        chrs = 'abdehkmnpswxzABDEFGHKMNPQRSTWXZ123456789';
        var str = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * chrs.length);
            str += chrs.substring(pos,pos+1);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Вот. Вас подбодрили и вы сразу научились сами программировать.